# How to properly export TypeScript methods in node.js app

Tags: node.js, typescript

In my node.js app, I have a TypeScript file (util.ts) that defines methods:

```
export function myFunc() { console.log(42); }
```

And I use it in another typescript file:

```
const util = require('./util');
util.myFunc();
```

This works fine, but the type of `util` const is `any`. How can I make it typed, in a way that when I type `util.`, my editor will know how to auto-complete, and when I write:

```
util.myOtherFunc();
```

TypeScript compiler will fail and say that `util` doesn't have a `myOtherFunc` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make it typed

Instead of :

```
const util = require('./util');
```

Do :

```
import util = require('./util');
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: I tried using import, but it failed. Further checking revealed that because our TypeScript project was ported from JavaScript, we were still using the node.js syntax exports.myFunc (and not as I wrote in my question), and when I tried to import it, I got "error TS2306: File 'util.ts' is not a module.". I now realize that I need to use the TypeScript syntax "export function" for the TypeScript compiler to consider this as a module and transform it to the "exports.myFunc =" form. Thanks for answering!